# Fastest access of a file using Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I need fastest access to a single file, several copies of which are stored in many systems using Hadoop. I also need to finding the ping time for each file in a sorted manner.
How should I approach learning hadoop to accomplish this task?
Please help fast.I have very less time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need faster access to a file just increase the replication factor to that file using [setrep](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.21.0/file_system_shell.html#setrep) command. This might not increase the file throughput proportionally, because of your current hardware limitations.

The [ls](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.21.0/file_system_shell.html#ls) command is not giving the access time for the directories and the files, it's showing the modification time only. Use the [Offline Image Viewer](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/docs/r0.21.0/hdfs_imageviewer.html) to dump the contents of hdfs fsimage files to human-readable formats. Below is the command using the Indented option.

> bin/hdfs oiv -i fsimagedemo -p Indented -o fsimage.txt

A sample o/p from the fsimage.txt, look for the ACCESS_TIME column.

```
INODE
  INODE_PATH = /user/praveensripati/input/sample.txt
  REPLICATION = 1
  MODIFICATION_TIME = 2011-10-03 12:53
  ACCESS_TIME = 2011-10-03 16:26
  BLOCK_SIZE = 67108864
  BLOCKS [NUM_BLOCKS = 1]
    BLOCK
      BLOCK_ID = -5226219854944388285
      NUM_BYTES = 529
      GENERATION_STAMP = 1005
  NS_QUOTA = -1
  DS_QUOTA = -1
  PERMISSIONS
    USER_NAME = praveensripati
    GROUP_NAME = supergroup
    PERMISSION_STRING = rw-r--r--
```

To get the ping time in a sorted manner, you need to write a shell script or some other program to extract the  INODE_PATH and ACCESS_TIME for each of the INODE section and then sort them based on the ACCESS_TIME. You can also use Pig as shown [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/docs/r0.21.0/hdfs_imageviewer.html#Files+That+Have+Never+Been+Accessed).

> How should I approach learning hadoop to accomplish this task? Please help fast.I have very less time.

If you want to learn Hadoop in a day or two it's not possible. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313788/how-to-start-learning-hadoop/7314083#7314083) are some videos and articles to start with.